# Ocaml editor on ubuntu : how to build the project?

Tags: ocaml, atom-editor

I installed atom on ubuntu 16.10, and the plugins language-ocaml, with nuclide and merlin, and all the necessary stuff.
the edition of an ML files is good, I have the autocompletion, the error checking... but I can't compile the file. Obviously, I can do it manually in the terminal, but I would like to use those of atom; and by the way I would appreciate to manage in debugging ML files! What I saw seems atractive!

when I try "package"/"build"/"build project" I get the error :

```
no eligible build target.
no configuration to build the project exists
```

and if I try "packages"/"build"/"select active target"... atom freezes...

I would be interrested in hints, answers, tutorials... buy the way, there are a lot of tutorials on the net but I did not yet found something that would help me to discover the ocaml extension in atom.

thank you

lowley

Answer (score 0):

The `build` package requires additional build providers to be installed. A list of available providers can be found on [their website](https://atombuild.github.io/), but there seems to be none for Ocaml.